# Export Results from Developer Console - Query Editor?

Tags: developer-console

I'm a huge fan of the [Query Editor](http://na7.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/code_dev_console_tab_query_editor.htm) in the SFDC Developer Console:

[image: screenshot of query editor with results]

**Is there a way to export the table of results as JSON/csv/excel or in some format that can be consumed by Excel?**

(I know that I can replicate the functionality in DemandTools or other tools, but sometimes when I've thrown up a query for debugging, it would be really handy to be able to export and manipulate the results.)

Comment: The dev console was not built for this. You can copy your query and paste it in the Force.com data loader. Its a powerful tool.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The Developer Workbench will allow you to, among other things, build SOQL queries and save the results as CSV: https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

Comment: Good call - I find the Developer Console quicker for quick exploration and debugging, but good to remember that I can always copy my query over to Workbench.

Comment: Sadly the Developer Workbench is restricted, when it comes down to relationship or aggregate queries. There are often times, when the Developer console is the only way to get the results.

Answer (score 53):

**UPDATE**
For faster use add a bookmark, pick a name and paste the following code to the URL:

```
javascript:(function(){function e(e){var t=new RegExp(/["]/g),n=e.replace(t,"“"),t=new RegExp(/\<[^\<]+\>/g),n=n.replace(t,"");return""==n?"":'"'+n+'"'}for(var t=document.evaluate("//div[@id='editors-body']/div[not(contains(@style,'display:none') or contains(@style,'display: none'))]//table/tbody/tr",document,null,0,null),n=[];row=t.iterateNext();){for(var o=row.getElementsByTagName("td"),a=[],r=0;r<o.length;r++)a.push(e(o[r].textContent));n.push(a)}for(var d="data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,filename=download.csv,",l=[],r=0;r<n.length;r++)l.push(n[r].join(","));d+=l.join("\r\n");var c=document.createElement("a");c.setAttribute("href",encodeURI(d)),c.setAttribute("download","dev_console.csv"),document.body.appendChild(c),c.click()})();
```

Save it. Now with one click it will download console results into `csv` file. (Tested in Chrome)

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**
I have a quick solution which works for me since I do a lot of exports from console. Script opens a new window with raw data in csv format and a link to a downloadable csv file. My script works in Chrome, didn't check it in other browsers.

1. Select the tab you want to export ( script takes only active tab )
2. Press F12 ( firebug window ) and go to console.
3. Copy / paste the following script and press enter. Don't forget to allow to pop a window ( Chrome usually blocks it ).
4. Enjoy..

var o = document.evaluate("//div[@id='editors-body']/div[not(contains(@style,'display:none') or contains(@style,'display: none'))]//table/tbody/tr",document,null,0,null);
var r = [];
while(row = o.iterateNext()){
    var cols = row.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var a = [];

    for(var i=0; i<cols.length; i++){
        a.push( formatData( cols[i].textContent ) );
    }

    r.push( a );
}

// generating csv file
var csv = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,filename=download.csv,";
var rows = [];

for(var i=0; i<r.length; i++){
    rows.push( r[i].join(",") );
}

csv += rows.join('\r\n');

popup(csv);

function formatData(input) {
    // replace " with “
    var regexp = new RegExp(/["]/g);
    var output = input.replace(regexp, "“");
    //HTML
    var regexp = new RegExp(/\<[^\<]+\>/g);
    var output = output.replace(regexp, "");
    if (output == "") return '';
    return '"' + output + '"';
}

// showing data in window for copy/ paste
function popup(data) {
    var generator = window.open('', 'csv', 'height=400,width=600');
    generator.document.write('<html><head><title>CSV</title>');
    generator.document.write('</head><body style="overflow: hidden;">');
    generator.document.write('<a href="'+encodeURI(csv)+'" download="Sf_export.csv">Download CSV</a><br>');
    generator.document.write('<textArea style="width: 100%; height: 97%;" wrap="off" >');
    generator.document.write(data);
    generator.document.write('</textArea>');
    generator.document.write('</body></html>');
    generator.document.close();
    return true;
}

Comment: Works great,  I might try to make this into a chrome extension.  Are you cool with me using your code?

Comment: @NSjonas yea, absolutely, please go on :D I found another option which works great, I use a tool called `aside.io`, it's kind of browser IDE and they let you export any results and edit / remove query results. Worth a try!

Comment: @NSjonas I updated my answer, the easiest way is to use a bookmark, it's just one click.

Comment: @NSjonas Superuseful! Is this the one?
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sdfc-dev-console-data-exp/mfcddagpdnfokfnbnoeephmfoifgdbid?utm_source=gmail

Comment: Somehow the 'bookmark' variant doesn't work for me because dev console opens in another window and it seems 'bookmark' runs in the main chrome tab from which dev console originated :?

Answer (score 29):

I have a quick and dirty solution :()

First open a console and query some records. Then open a FireBug window (F12, i hope you have it). Select the query results table with a firebug's select arrow. You need to turn off the css styles `-moz-user-select: none` for the `<div id="gridview-1182"` to be able to select the result text. Then select all results just with a mouse, copy and paste it to Excel. Works great for me!

Step 1: activate user select

[image]

Step 2: select results

[image]

Step 3: copy & paste it to excel

[image]

Comment: Just to add I just tried this with the "Overall Code Coverage" table and it works there also =]

Comment: I like this dirty solution as I could not use workbench due to some firewall stuff.

Comment: I just did something similar from Chrome, without FireBug. After executing my query, I opened the Developer Console, found the main `<table>` that all the data was in, and copied it to a new HTML file. From there, I had an unformatted HTML table that I could easily copy into Excel 

Comment: Works as expected, someone still struggling can follow the inspect element till where @Sergej has mentioned, and once there, simply remove `x-unselectable` and you should be able to select all the text!

Something like:

`<div id="gridview-1506" class="x-grid-view x-fit-item x-grid-view-default" style="overflow: auto; margin: 0px; width: 1914px; height: 611px;" tabindex="-1">`

Answer (score 5):

Download the [SDFC Dev Console Data Exporter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sdfc-dev-console-data-exp/mfcddagpdnfokfnbnoeephmfoifgdbid) Chrome's extension to get the data in CSV format.

Comment: The link is for the chrome extension.  There is not that should be copied from there!

Comment: This solutions is awesome because it includes the headers and is extremely easy to use.

Comment: @mPeixoto,  download in csv and copy from there.  and mostly people really want data export which is not supported in developer console.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way:

1. Run your query in query builder.
2. Hit F-12 and click on any row of the query builder's result.
3. In developer console switch from tr to table.
4. Copy table's html and paste into notepad.
5. save notepad as html and open it in a browser.
6. you can easily copy your desired rows or whole result set from here.

Answer (score 1):

I found a tool which I use for just exports from console. It's kind of free browser IDE called `aside.io` where you can actually export in `csv` format, bulk delete or do other things with queries.

[image]

For me it's much better than custom scripts. **Disclaimer:** I'm not associated with aside.io in any ways.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [dataloader.io](http://dataloader.io/) you can select your object, columns and make a custom select query, then export all to CSV.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few others have mentioned external tools. I help make the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fishofprey.com/2016/12/fuseit-sfdc-explorer-34163492.html), which is free from my <strike>current</strike> previous employer.

With it you can export the results to CSV or directly to the clipboard.

[image]

Comment: looks great, why it's note widely used?

Comment: @PAS One limitation is that it is Windows only and requires a client side executable. For some people that is fine, for others it is a blocker.

Comment: can you convert it as VS Code extension? I bet you will get lot more downloads that way.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the Execute Anonymous Window.
Especially useful if a straightforward query doesn't refine your data enough.
Here's trivial example finding contacts from a phone area then filtering account names less than 11 characters long.

Note the extra comma before the first field to separate the debug info from the other fields.
Also, Excel treats some numeric text as numbers and can corrupt them. Prefix with a letter to avoid this.

```
Contact[] queriedObjects = [Select ID, Name, Account.Name, MobilePhone, Phone 
FROM Contact WHERE Phone LIKE '0161%'  ORDER BY lastname];
system.debug(queriedObjects.size());
Integer Count =0;
String strTest;
for (Contact e : queriedObjects) {
    strTest = e.Name;
    if (strTest.length() <= 10){
        Count += 1;
        system.debug(','+e.Name + ', T'+ e.Phone + ', '+e.Account.Name);
    }//endif  
}//next
system.debug(count);
```

Execute the code;
Download the debug log to text;
In notepad, remove unwanted debug lines before and after the actual desired field values;
Save as csv and open in Excel;
Remove the first column (the debug statements).