# Is there any way to get list of all apex classes along with code coverages?

Tags: code-coverage

I wan to check code coverage for individual Apex class after I ran all test classes.

> Is there way way where I can fire SOQL query get the list of All apex
>   class along with individual code coverages of my ORG?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you need a SOQL??. After the execution of test classes,i.e., "Run All tests" is completed. click on "Developer Console" button. At bottom right section of this window you'll find code coverage of each apex class and overall coverage of your org.

Moreover her's a SOQL that gives coverage of each class-

```
SELECT ApexClassOrTrigger.Name, NumLinesCovered, NumLinesUncovered FROM ApexCodeCoverageAggregate ORDER BY ApexClassOrTrigger.Name ASC
```

Note- Please, check the checkbox "Use tolling API"

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. Is there any way where I can extract in excel file?

Comment: Do I need to Install tools api for this?

Comment: @DhananjayPatil since you want to extrct this data as excel sheet. Here's what you can do. Create a class in this class use the above query and populate a list. Now, create a new VisualForce page add your controller to this page . Create a grid/table in your page and use the list you populated in your controller. Now add the following attributes in your VF page tag "standardStylesheets="false" cache="true" contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#NameOfYourSheet.xls""

Comment: Thanks Gaurav.I will surely look into this option as this needs development.

Comment: I have found an interesting site aside.io where u have to login from ur org and you can also run all test classes and check the code coverage for each apex class and u can also download the csv file for ur reference. :)

Answer (score 2):

Beyond the Developer Console, you can check the code coverage results using the Tooling API. Specifically the [ApexCodeCoverageAggregate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexcodecoverageaggregate.htm) and [ApexCodeCoverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexcodecoverage.htm) classes.

The Tooling API SOQL query can use the ApexClassorTriggerId field to select the specific class (or trigger) you want the coverage results for.

There are a few ways to get this out to Excel. See [Export Results from Developer Console - Query Editor?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/15328/102)

Comment: For this I have to install Tools api then :) Thanks

Comment: @DhananjayPatil It is possible to do this directly via the Developer Console. When running the SOQL query there is a checkbox to use the Tooling API. If that doesn't appear you may need to enable it in the developer console options. There are a number of tools that can be used to export the Tooling API results if you need.

Comment: I can not find the checkbox in my developer console? Can tell me how can i enable it..

Comment: I have found an interesting site https://www.aside.io/ where u have to login from ur org and you can also run all test classes and check the code coverage for each apex class and u can also download the csv file for ur reference. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can actually get the code coverage extract by using Salesforce Advance Code Searcher, just add this plugin to your browser->login to your org-> click on setup-> you will be able to see ' **View and Download your Organisation's Code Coverage**' -> click download-> the extract of the code coverage will be downloaded as a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to export the results to CSV you can try by sfdx trying something like this:

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT ApexClassOrTrigger.Name, NumLinesCovered, NumLinesUncovered FROM ApexCodeCoverageAggregate ORDER BY ApexClassOrTrigger.Name ASC" -u myOrg -t -r csv > .\output\result.csv
```

[Here you can check the sfdx documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_data.htm#cli_reference_force_data_soql_query)