# Query error but no error showing

Tags: soql, workbench

I am attempting to use workbench to run a query:

```
select count(id), Response_CD__c, DAY_ONLY(createddate) from outreach_phone_detail_pd__c where createddate > 2019-10-10T00:00:00Z group by Response_CD__c,DAY_ONLY(createddate)
```

Unfortunately, this query only returns 2 rows so it shows without the "DAY_ONLY(createddate)"

this leaves the data unreadable as it IS seperated by day but you don't know which line is which day.

This query shows no errors or execution failures

results picture:
[image]

Comment: What's the actual output look like? What are you expecting? Please [edit] your question so we can assist you.

Comment: Please do not use put-downs or direct sarcasm at users in your posts. Respectful communication is part of the core Stack Exchange ethos.

Comment: I'm almost wondering if this is a bug with Workbench. Running a very similar query in developer console, I was able to get the expected 3-column result.

Comment: @DrewKennedy in salesforce dev console i am also getting 3 columns, any idea how to export it in a readable manner for a report?

Comment: Not cleanly, but I have done [this before](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/15332/49715). Just note it does require FireFox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this may just be a bug in workbench or is not supported,

Drew Kennedy posted a comment which is the solution I ended up going with, using a plugin to pull from Dev console.
[Export Results from Developer Console - Query Editor?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15328/export-results-from-developer-console-query-editor/15332#15332)